# Trying to escape parenthesis when passing arguments in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I made a PowerShell script that will send a toast notification via/arguments. In the script, I use the `param` function in the beginning of the script something like....this

```
param($UserID)
```

Now I open a command prompt to load a PowerShell script and adding these arguments

```
powershell C:\file\in\directory\PowershellScript.ps1 -UserID "Mikey (TEST)"
```

When I sent the prompt over to PowerShell, it gave me this red error that says

```
TEST : The term 'TEST' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:64
```

Assumingly the parentheses `(` `)` could be the culprit as PowerShell is thinking of loading a module of some sort instead of applying as a string value. I even tried escaping the parentheses using the backslash `\(TEST\)` but that didn't work either as it said `TEST\ : The term 'TEST\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`.

Is there something I'm missing or something part of a script I should add to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes inside the ps command:

```
powershell C:\file\in\directory\PowershellScript.ps1 -UserID 'Mikey (TEST)'
```